# How to add several panels to script palette in Digital Micrograph GMS 2.x

Tags: user-interface, dialog, dm-script

I'm wondering how to add several UI panels to a scripting palette in GMS 2.x. I found some commands in Gatan's outdated documentation (http://digitalmicrograph-scripting.tavernmaker.de/other%20resources/Old-DMHelp/FloatingPalettes.htm) but most of them are not found in GMS 2.32.

Given a UI class "UI_class" (including an init() function that creates the interface) I've already successfully registered the script palette and opened the corresponding gadget using:

`object UI=Alloc(UI_class).init()
RegisterScriptPalette(UI,"Type","Display")
OpenGadgetPanel("Display")`

Unfortunately, the command `GadgetWindowAddGadgetPanel()` which seemed to be the most promising to me in the first instance in order to add a second UI to the same palette cannot be found.

Does anybody know a working equivalent?

Thank you in advance for sharing your experience, I'm looking forward to see some nicely designed floating palettes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the question correctly. Each UI derived object forms it's own "dialog", which can be displayed either as

- Modal Dialog  - using `Pose( DlgObj )`
  [image]
- Modeless Dialog - using `Display( DlgObj, "name" )`
  [image]
- Gadget panel - by first 'registering' it and then displaying a registed dialog
  [image]

If you have multiple gadget of **same width**, you can add them together by drag-and drop. This is not part of the dialog - just part of how the UI interaction with dialogs. ( You drag a palette to the side of the screen to attach it, and then you can dragg other palettes on top of it. )

[image] |
[image] |
[image]

---

Example script to produce some dialogs:

```
Object CreateDlgObj()
{
    TagGroup DialogTG   = DLGCreateDialog("My Dialog")
    TagGroup StrFieldTG = DLGCreateStringField("Some string",20)
    DialogTG.DLGAddElement(StrFieldTG)
    Object DialogObj = Alloc(UIFrame)
    DialogOBJ.Init(DialogTG)
    return DialogObj
}

// MAIN

// Show dialog as modal dialog
//  CreateDLGObj().Pose()

// Show dialog as modeless dialog
//  CreateDLGObj().Display( "NewName" )

// Register dialog as gadget and then display
// RegisterScriptPalette( CreateDLGObj(),"", "RegDlg" )
// OpenGadgetPanel( "RegDlg" )

// Create, register and display multiple dialogs as palettes
number nMax = 2
For( number i =0; i<nMax; i++)
{
    string name = "MyDlg_" + i
    RegisterScriptPalette( CreateDLGObj(),"", name )
    OpenGadgetPanel( name )
}
```

---

Note that "Gadget panels" or "tool palettes" or whatever you call them are different in GMS 1.x, GMS 2.x and GMS 3.x as it is always the "main program" which decides how to handle the dialogs. GMS 2.x is the only version, where the program "remembers" the layout of multiple such palettes. These layouts can be saved and loaded. GMS 3 no longer has this, as all UI palettes are fixed in position. (Old custom dialogs still appear, but in a somewhat 'out-of-style' way.

#### GMS 2.x's "Floating Window Layout" tool:

[image]

The "layout" information stored with this tool is actually stored in the Windows registry.
[image]

But I have never used that so far. (And it also only applies to GMS 2.x.)

---

It is also worth mentioning, that `RegisterScriptPalette` does exactly what is says: It adds the UI *permanently* to the list of palettes the appliction knows of.

So running the script twice, you get *two* identical palettes. You usually don't want that! Just use `OpenGadgetPanel` to show any already registered palette.

However, 'registered' palettes will only remain 'registered' as long as the application is running, so they are gone at restart of DM.

If you want somethng more persistent, you need to install the code as a *Library* via the File menu. Note, that any *executeable* part of the code will be automatically run on startup. So you want to have the `RegisterScriptPalette` be part of that code, but not the `OpenGadgetPanel`.

Comment: Brilliant, quick and absolute clarifying answer, thank you! Palettes start making much more sense to me now :-)